# creating dynamic droplist with ajax jquery php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, drop-down-menu

i am creating a simple dynamic drop list  that the populate of the second one is based on the selection of the first one   but the problem is that  the first droplist do not populate anything  so i can not use the second one 
can anyone help me ??

## dbconfig.php

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "****";
$password = "******";
$db = "cat";
?>
```

## select.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#category").change(function(){
            $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#type").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            var id = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
            $.post("select_type.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                $("select#type").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("select#type").html(data);
            });
        });
        $("form#select_form").submit(function(){
            var cat = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
            var type = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');
            if(cat>0 && type>0)
            {
                var result = $("select#type option:selected").html();
                $("#result").html('your choice: '+result);
            }
            else
            {
                $("#result").html("you must choose two options!");
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php include "select.class.php"; ?>
        <form id="select_form">
            Choose a category:<br />
            <select id="category">
            <?php echo $opt->ShowCategory(); ?>
            </select>
            <br /><br />

           choose a type:<br />
            <select id="type">
                <option value="0">choose...</option>
            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="confirm" />
        </form>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## select _class.php

```
<?php 
 class SelectList
{
    protected $conn;

        public function __construct()

        {
           $this->DbConnect();
        }
    protected function DbConnect()
   {
    include "dbconfig.php";
    $this->conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) OR die("Unable to connect to the database");
    mysql_select_db($db,$this->conn) OR die("can not select the database $db");
    return TRUE;
   }  

    public function ShowCategory()
    {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $category = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $category .= '<option value="' . $row['id_cat'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
            }
            return $category;

    }
    public function ShowType()
   {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM type WHERE id_cat=$_POST[id]";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
    $type = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
      {
        $type .= '<option value="' . $row['id_type'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
      }
    return $type;
   }

}   
$opt = new SelectList();   

?>
```

## select_type.php

```
<?php
include "select.class.php";
echo $opt->ShowType();
?>
```

## table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id_cat` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_cat`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `categories`
--

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id_cat`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'colours'),
(2, 'flowers'),
(3, 'tools');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `type`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `type` (
  `id_type` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_cat` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `type`
--

INSERT INTO `type` (`id_type`, `id_cat`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'yellow'),
(2, 1, 'green'),
(3, 1, 'red'),
(4, 1, 'gray'),
(5, 1, 'white'),
(6, 2, 'daisy'),
(7, 2, 'cowslip'),
(8, 2, 'lily'),
(9, 2, 'sunflower'),
(10, 3, 'hammer'),
(11, 3, 'screwdriver'),
(12, 3, 'spatula'),
(13, 3, 'wrench'),
(14, 3, 'clamp');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is you are trying to access ShowCategory() using $opt->ShowCategory()

But you are not creating object of the class SelectList. You should do this

```
$opt = new SelectList();
```

Comment: but i did create $opt = new SelectList();  in the select_class.php

Comment: May be the object is not available in the other place when u include it using include function. var_dump($opt) will help to debug.

Comment: i did the var dump($opt) in the select _class.php

Comment: I want u to do it in Select.php after your include your class.

Comment: i did the var dump($opt) in the select _class.php it display **object(SelectList)[1]
  protected 'conn' => resource(5, mysql link)**